# How do you make a GlobalFilter that logs 404s in Spring Cloud Gateway

Tags: java, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm trying to diagnose a problem where I am getting [random 404s in my requests](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/issues/2174).  So I put in a `GlobalFilter` like this

```
@Component
public class PerformanceRequestIDPostFilter implements GlobalFilter {
    @Override
    public Mono<Void> filter(final ServerWebExchange exchange, GatewayFilterChain chain) {

        final long startNanos = System.nanoTime();
        return chain
            .filter(exchange)
            .then(
                Mono.fromRunnable(
                    () -> {
                        final String requestURI = exchange.getRequest().getURI().toASCIIString();
                        final String method = exchange.getRequest().getMethodValue();

                        final long requestTimeNano = System.nanoTime() - startNanos;
                        final double requestTimeInMillis = (double) requestTimeNano * 0.000001;
                        final HttpStatus statusCode = Objects.requireNonNull(exchange.getResponse().getStatusCode());
                        final int status = statusCode.value();
                        final String requestTimeInMillisText = String.format("%.03f", requestTimeInMillis);
                        if (statusCode.is4xxClientError()) {
                            log.warn(LOG_MESSAGE_FORMAT, traceId, method, requestURI, status, requestTimeInMillisText);
                        } else if (statusCode.isError()) {
                            log.error(LOG_MESSAGE_FORMAT, traceId, method, requestURI, status, requestTimeInMillisText);
                        } else {
                            log.info(LOG_MESSAGE_FORMAT, traceId, method, requestURI, status, requestTimeInMillisText);
                        }
                        final HttpHeaders responseHeaders = exchange.getResponse().getHeaders();
                        if (responseHeaders.getAccessControlAllowOrigin() == null) {
                            responseHeaders.setAccessControlAllowOrigin("*");
                        }

                    })
            );
    }
}
```

For the most part everything is okay for 500 and 200 but for 404 it's not logging anything.  I am presuming there's something filtering beforehand, but I am not sure where or how to bypass it.

Answer (score 1):

I just had a similar issue and it turns out for me it was an inconsistency with `spring.cloud.gateway.discovery.locator.include-expression`. Some instances of a service failed the expression and others didn't. It looks like it will poll every once in a while and re-check the condition, but it isn't guaranteed to check the same instance every time, so it will mark the service as down if it happens to pick one that fails the condition

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-gateway/blob/71014d10bfa040a08d3479b161b79b3c8cd0d4a8/spring-cloud-gateway-server/src/main/java/org/springframework/cloud/gateway/discovery/DiscoveryClientRouteDefinitionLocator.java#L90-L99